# v-tooltip only for append-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I continue to deal with Vuetify.
Tell me how you can apply a tooltip **only** for *append-icon* in a *v-text-field*?
Now tooltip does not work for icons at all!
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Meller008/pen/jObwKar?editors=1010)

```
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        label="Regular"
        v-on="on"
        append-icon="event"
        style="max-width: 200px"
      />
    </template>
    <span>Tooltip</span>
  </v-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way to solve this (By some API option) - The component renders the icon outside of the text-area (Open GitHub issue/feature if you want).

[image]

Anyway if you use a simple `<v-icon>` component it works fine.

Extra details here:
[Wrapping v-icon with v-tooltip inside text-field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135021/wrapping-v-icon-with-v-tooltip-inside-text-field)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field label="Hello world">
          <v-tooltip slot="append">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-icon v-on="on" color="primary" dark>
                  mdi-calendar
                </v-icon>
              </template>
            <span>My Tooltip</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought so)