# Why isn't the v-icon displayed inside the v-text-field?

Tags: vuetify.js

Can you tell me why the icon to the right of the v-text-field is not displayed?
I want to make the calendar open when you click on the icon.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Meller008/pen/jObwKar?editors=1010)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-menu>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-text-field label="Hello world" style="max-width: 200px">
          <!--The icon is not displayed-->
          <v-icon v-on="on" color="primary" dark>event</v-icon>
        </v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker>
      </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

P.S.
Here is a good example. It's not mine.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/JamieCurnow/pen/KKPjraK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. I did this without the activator template.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Meller008/pen/xxwaZXV) [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#absolute-position-without-activator)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
       <v-text-field 
        label="Hello world"
        style="max-width: 200px"
        append-icon="event"
        @click:append="show">
        </v-text-field>
    <v-menu
     v-model="menu"
     :position-x="x"
     :position-y="y"
     absolute >
       <v-date-picker />
    </v-menu>
  </v-app>
</div>


show (e) {
        console.log(123);
        e.preventDefault();
        this.menu = false;
        this.x = e.clientX;
        this.y = e.clientY;
        this.$nextTick(() => {
         this.menu = true
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `input` field is empty https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

There's an attribute to prepend and append icons in textfields in Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icons

You simply need to add it:
`<v-text-field label="Hello world" style="max-width: 200px" append-icon="event">`

Comment: In this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135021/wrapping-v-icon-with-v-tooltip-inside-text-field ), we made the icon nested in the text-field. If you do as you say, then the calendar will not open when you click on the icon.